# How to configure --enable-libfreetype for FFMPEG on Windows 10?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to customize/remove timestamp from my FFMPEG recording.

I understand that I need to use the flag `:filter-v` or `-vf` in my command.

On googling, it seems that I need to use the flag --enable-libfreetype, but the command
`ffmpeg --enable-libfreetype ...` or `ffmpeg -enable-libfreetype ...`

returns this error

```
Unrecognized option '-enable-libfreetype'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Some answers on SO suggest to "compile" with the option --enable-libfreetype.

How to "compile" the libfreetype option? I am using Windows 10.

I tried finding online for a solution but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `--enable-libfreetype` is a configuration option set when generating ffmpeg binaries. It is not meant to be used during runtime (executing commands). Most builds already have libfreetype enabled. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: hi @Gyan I want to remove the timestamp completely from the recording

Comment: hi @Gyan I am unable to find anything that works for me to remove the timestamp on the top right corner..can u please help

Answer (score 0):

`--enable-libfreetype`
You can use the `./configure --help` to list enable-lib.

I don't know how about your installation for freetype2 ?